# Ansible limit playbook to ansible_hostname in ini inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

my inventory looks like this:

```
[Databases]
"DB1 - SQL 2012" ansible_host=DB1
"DB2 - SQL 2014" ansible_host=DB2
"DB3 - SQL 2017" ansible_host=DB3
```

Im using the string in the quotation marks as {{ inventory_hostname }} in multiple tasks for example to perform snapshots in vSphere. Regarding the Ansible documentation in an ini inventory, the first part should be the "alias" not the inventory_hostname, but alias is not working, maybe somebody can explain that aswell.

The bad thing about it is, that i can't limit the playbooks to run on one host:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml --limit DB1 -->
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: DB1

ansible-playbook test.yml --limit "DB1 - SQL 2012" -->
Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: DB1
Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: -
Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: SQL
Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: 2012
```

I guess the right setup would be something like:

```
[Databases]
DB1_SQL-2012 invenvory_hostname="DB1 - SQL 2012" ansible_host=DB1
DB2_SQL-2014 inventory_hostname="DB2 - SQL 2014" ansible_host=DB2
```

And i would be able to limit with DB1_SQL-2012, but i would like to keep the inventory as clean as possible. Does anyone has an idea how i can limit this to the ansible_host even if there is an alias/inventory_hostname present?

Comment: `i would like to keep the inventory as clean as possible` <= IMO a clean inventory uses whenever possible the full fqdn name needed to connect to the machine as the inventory hostname (which is not another var but simply the name used in the file for your host) without `ansible_host`. Regarding alias, you are mixing things up: it is simply the fact that you use an inventory name different form the targeted `ansible_host` address. In other words, my clean inventory does not uses aliases, unless for a specific reason like targeting same machine twice and they never contain spaces in that case.

Comment: And to finish with, `--limit`, as a `hosts` stanza in a playbook, is only aware of groups and intentory hostnames, not `ansible_hosts` declared for them (as several inventory names could use the same host anyway)

Comment: Ok i should've said, i want to keep the inventory as clean as possible without creating a host_vars file for each host :D In your opinion it should be DB1.dom.loc and i create a /host_vars/DB1.dom.loc.yml which contains inventory_hostname="DB1 - SQL 2012", or you would create a new variable like vsphere_hostname?
Well i can do that instead, but i'll miss the time where i just had to adjust one line in one file for the majority of the hosts :)

Comment: There is nothing such as `inventory_hostname="DB1 - SQL 2012"` to put anywhere in your inventory. This does not exist. `inventory_hostname` is created at inventory parse time by ansible from the name you declared in your inventory. If you use a full fqdn, you will also get `inventory_hostname_short` containing only the first name before the first dot.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless whether you use separate files or one file as the inventory: You decided to identify a host uniquely with a pattern like `"DB1 - SQL 2012"`. Although it looks strange to me that is ok for Ansible.

But now you want to abbreviate, or identify a host by looking at defined variables. This is documented as not working. Check [Limitation of Patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#limitations-of-patterns).

Comment: Yep, it seems like i should've thought a bit more about it before doing a setup like this :D I took the time to reduce all hosts to their hostname and created host_vars for them where i defined the vsphere_vmname variable to use it for what i used the inventory_hostname. Now i have about 50 files more, but i guess it's the right approach if i ever need additional host_vars. Thanks you two :)